# lua : will memory still using if the image create as local?

Tags: memory, lua, coronasdk

```
local function myInit()
    local topBackGround = display.newImageRect("backGround.png", 500, 500)
    topBackGround.x = 0
    topBackGround.y = 0
end
```

as i know local variable will not using memory after we jump out the function, as this case the image still exits, will it using memory ?

if no, what if i insert it to a global displayGroup ?

Answer (score 1):

Lua is garbage collected. So it will still exist until Lua collects it. Since nobody has a reference to the object anymore, it can be collected anytime after the function exists.

However, the fact nothing has a reference to the object means that you couldn't use it anyway. You could create a new one, but it would be a *new* object, not the same one as before. Now, because Corona caches images, it may internally refer to the same image if the original wasn't collected. But it's *terribly* bad form to do this.

Anytime you create something in Lua, if you want to keep it around, then you need to actually keep it around. Keep a reference to it.

Put it another way. This:

```
display.newImageRect("backGround.png", 500, 500)
```

Returns a value. A *unique* value. Any variables declared `local` are discarded after their scope ends (unless they are captured by functions as closures).

If at any time, your program cannot find a value, because all references to it are discarded, then that value will be eliminated. Therefore, if you want to be able to use something, you need to keep it in a place where you can get at it. Otherwise, Lua knows you can't find it and will delete it.

Comment: that's what i heard too, anything that have nothing pointing at will be collect, but i did a local backGround = display.newImageRect in a function but the image remain all the time, i even do collectgarbage("collect") sometimes.

Comment: @FunFair: How do you know that it is still around? You don't have a pointer to it.